# Power BI Gateway Architecture for SaaS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

We are a SaaS provider and would like to open up our data to clients through Power BI. Our solution is hosted in AWS with an RDS database and we plan to make the database available through a Power BI Gateway to RDS.

I am currently trying to work out a way to give my clients the ability to (a) design their own dashboard/reports and (b) embed these reports in our web app.

The plan is to embed reports into the webapp is by using the “Embed for your Organisation” approach where the users require a Power BI Pro account.

The key question I have is around managing the Gateway, data sources and data sets. Technically my company will host the Power BI GW in AWS and the idea was that we register the PowerBI GW in our account. Ideally we would then give client users access to either the data source itself or a data set based on it. However when trying to give access to a user of another organisation to either, then I get an error message saying “One or more users were not found within your organization.“.

I read about B2B Guest access but is pretty unclear to me and my first tests were not successful.

Can anyone point me to a reasonable architecture or approach for this?

Please note that for cost reasons, we want to avoid Power BI Premium and Capacities and cost is a constraint.

Comment: i know its been a while, but did you found a solution or could you share your experience? facing similar requirements

Comment: @AndreaInglese - We went down the rabbit hole of hosting a Gateway and managing guest accounts for one client in our ActiveDirectory. We are not ActiveDirectory experts and may have done that wrong but it was/is pain to administer and manage client users.
For subsequent implementations, we just provide access to a read replica of the database which sits in the DMZ/public subnet. If a client wants to connect, they connect to the replica and manage the Gateway and Power BI Service themselves. We only provide a sample PBIX.